# Laravel Eloquent Model Properties

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

My scenario is:

PHP Script 1:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->email = 'email@emailness.com';
$user->save();
```

PHP Script 2:

```
$user = User::find(1);
while ($user->email != 'email@emailness.com') {

    /** Do stuff **/

}
```

Now my question is, does the email variable get updated when it's updated from another script? For example, Script 2 runs, while it runs, Script 1 also runs. Will the while statement update and move since the condition isn't true anymore?

Comment: If script 2 is left running, then it won't currently pick up changes made by script 1. This is because the `User::find()` is done outside the loop, and is not read again. Copy that inside the loop (you need it where it is also) and then `sleep(5);` so you don't wear your database out. Then it should work.

Comment: Ok, so you need to initiate the class again? Thanks, that was what I was looking for. Wasn't sure if it was necessary.

Comment: You can use locking. http://laravel.com/docs/queries#pessimistic-locking

Comment: Thanks Anam for the suggestion, I'll look into it.

Comment: Do you know if there is some kind of reload method built into Eloquent or is just resetting the variable the best solution?

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve here? Have a daemon that's constantly running, checking for e-mails being updated? Or have a specific bit of code executed when any user or a spefic user updates their e-mail?

Comment: The code is constantly running and when the login model is updated, those changes need to take effect on the Daemon process too.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to achieve something like this is to run a query every minute or so checking for updated columns. The alternative would be to make your daemon run some sort of server which gets pinged by a model event.

If you only need to monitor a single user's email, it's easy enough - `User::find($id);` then `sleep(60)`. If you need to monitor more than one user it gets a bit trickier.

If your model uses timestamps (created_at and updated_at), it's possible to query only for models that have been updated recently. Let's say you want to re-query the database every 60 seconds - what we want to do is query all User models that have an updated_at greater than 60 seconds ago.

I'll use the Carbon class, which is an extension of DateTime included with Laravel, but you can also construct a normal DateTime object or a datetime string manually.

```
$dt = Carbon\Carbon::now()->subSeconds(60);
$users = User::where('updated_at', '>=', $dt)
    ->get();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    // do something with users that have been updated
}

sleep(60);
```

You can also replace `get()` with `lists('email')` if you only want a flat array of emails of updated users.

There may also be more efficient ways than using `sleep(60)`, maybe using Symfony's Process class, but I'll not get into that here.